# Axios request throws 431 error on every request only in google chrome

Tags: reactjs, api, google-chrome, axios

I am getting 431 in every request-response only in google chrome. Except for google chrome is working fine in all browsers. I debugged a lot but did not find which thing caused it.

**Pacakage.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
  }
```

Here are my Axios configurations, that I'm using as middleware. Every request goes through this.

```
export default ({ type, method, path, success, isFormData, isBlob, newUrl }) =>
  function* (action) {
    const {
      body,
      params,
      success: successPayload,
      fail: failPayload,
      successMessage
    } = action.payload || {};
    console.log("action.payload", action.payload);
    const idToken = localStorage.getItem("idToken") || "";
    let header = {};

    if (!isFormData) {
      header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      };
    }
    header["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";

    if (idToken !== "") {
      header["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${idToken}`;
    }

    try {
      yield put({
        type: requestPending(type)
      });

      let options = {
        url: `${typeof path === "function" ? path(action.payload) : path}`,
        method: method,
        headers: header,
        data: body,
        params,
      };
      if (isBlob) {
        options.responseType = "blob";
      }
      let res = yield call(axios.request, options);

    } catch (err) {
      const errRes = get(err, "response", err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: HTTP 431 is "Request Header Fields Too Large". You should inspect the failing request in Chrome's network inspector and figure out why there's an overly long header.

Comment: @AKX, I inspected the request and the request headers have only jwt token which is also according to oAuth standard. I facing the issue only in google chrome except it. it working fine in all browsers.

Comment: Really? _Only_? My Chrome sends e.g. `accept`, `accept-encoding`, `accept-language`, `cookie`, `dnt`, `referer`, `sec-ch-ua`, ... for a simple `fetch("/")` request on SO.

Comment: @AKX, all these headers by default attach to every request. but I am talking about only the custom header that I am passing to the request,  that's why I said my request only has jwt token.